# C# web api using Google access token

Tags: c#, oauth, webapi

I am trying to make external login. I registered with Google and I am getting back access token from this link:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?scope=openid%20email&response_type=token&redirect_uri=https://localhost:3007/google-singin&client_id=655720894976-2rkkoov9efteqna8hq3vbc632brur2jf.apps.googleusercontent.com
```

it returns :

```
https://localhost:3007/google-singin#access_token=ya29.a0AX9GBdVlBg-Vym3C1oSpjGljuGyuhwDox3hvjgNEFe2ruPRYovteF6CwdSq-iU2njYwVIscBKty8MrROxNz-nP0RYnEhIgAhqxb6AXJ2XGGXU0aAvbqRXXGcPNSRhA3I6q1547bJuxYFbNZ2NFg9iErztQnJaCgYKAW8SARASFQHUCsbCwxPiOUQq4k126M0x1ZgBPg0163&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3599&scope=email%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email%20openid&authuser=0&prompt=consent
```

from this I can get access token witch is :

```
ya29.a0AX9GBdVlBg-Vym3C1oSpjGljuGyuhwDox3hvjgNEFe2ruPRYovteF6CwdSq-iU2njYwVIscBKty8MrROxNz-nP0RYnEhIgAhqxb6AXJ2XGGXU0aAvbqRXXGcPNSRhA3I6q1547bJuxYFbNZ2NFg9iErztQnJaCgYKAW8SARASFQHUCsbCwxPiOUQq4k126M0x1ZgBPg0163
```

How do I call Google API with this token, to get user info? I mean in back end.

If I call this links:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json&access_token=ya29.a0AX9GBdVlBg-Vym3C1oSpjGljuGyuhwDox3hvjgNEFe2ruPRYovteF6CwdSq-iU2njYwVIscBKty8MrROxNz-nP0RYnEhIgAhqxb6AXJ2XGGXU0aAvbqRXXGcPNSRhA3I6q1547bJuxYFbNZ2NFg9iErztQnJaCgYKAW8SARASFQHUCsbCwxPiOUQq4k126M0x1ZgBPg0163
```

I get proper user info. The problem is I want to use it in the back end.

Comment: Send your data to backend and use backend to connect to google api

Comment: I understand this but for me is not clear how to do it... I understand I need google Oatuh package. Could you write for me sample code how to call to get access key and how to use it to get user info

Comment: Send the access token as an authorization header of type bearer

Comment: @ModestasVacerskas we are not a coding service we will help you fix your code not do it for you

Comment: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-asp.net-core-3

Comment: I understand that you are not coding services, but I am still learning. Link you gave have 0 info on how to do it, and I was searching the internet for few days for examples and where is nothing that I could use.

Comment: @ModestasVacerskas as per your requirement, You want to communicate from app to app which requires client credentials flow. Generate this token on backend itself. You can use this package on your backed https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/get_started